# Auto email is generated when another column is edited

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, list-item, send-email

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Dqm.png)I am trying to send a auto email notification, when a specific column "A" is edited.

But this flow is considering to send an email even when another column "B" is edited (for which I have already created a separate flow).

Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you have any rules like A column changed to specific value then only Flow should be triggered ? or you want to trigger flow when A column value changed to any value?

Comment: When A column changed to specific value then only Flow should be triggered.

Comment: Also, I have assigned dropdown choice - "Approved by Manager". So when Manager acknowledges the list item he chooses the only available value that is "Approved by Manager" so the value is changed from blank to this.   After it is updated, an auto email 1 is sent to next stakeholder to input his answer in Column B. When he edits the Column B, email 2 is sent to all team members. But in the process when Column B is edited, email 1 is sent again along with email 2 which I want to fix. Thank you

Comment: In that case you might be using Trigger Condition in your power automate. Could you please share settings page of first activity i.e. trigger activity for both the flow which you are using?

Comment: For both the flow trigger condition looks as shown in the picture. Please let me know if I have to edit the trigger condition.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the **Has Colum Changed:** dynamic content from the **Get changes to an item or file (properties only)** action to see if the specific column value has changed. Please note that the list or library must have versioning enabled for this action to work correctly.

[image]

[image]

See these resources for more information:

[Blog post: Run a flow when a SharePoint column is modified](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/run-a-flow-when-a-sharepoint-column-is-modified/)

[YouTube video: Run a flow when a SharePoint column is modified](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvmi21KomK0)